# File not being created on run PHP Script via sh bash script Centos 6

Tags: php, ssh

I have a question regarding why via

php -q -f /home/user/public_html/file.php (this script contain a small script that create a file).

file.php content:

```
$csvFile = 'http://example.com/file.csv';


function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) !== FALSE) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<data/>');

foreach ($csv as $_item){
            $itm = $xml->addChild('produs');
            $itm->addAttribute('city', $_item[0]);
            $itm->addAttribute('street', $_item[2]);
            $itm->addAttribute('number', $_item[3]);
            $itm->addAttribute('user', '0');
        }

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$formattedXML = $dom->saveXML();

$xmlFilePath = 'file.xml';
//i solved the issue with '/home/path/to/be/stored/'
$fp = fopen($xmlFilePath,'w+');
fwrite($fp, $formattedXML);
fclose($fp);
```

The issue is that on execute the command the file is not created, but on access on web via http it is created.

There is no error, it just say that the file has been created but is not.

Centos 6 - Minimal Server
Nginx, PHP-FPM.
User www-data and root, both does the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your audit.log for relevant SELinux AVC denied messages.

Comment: You need to do error checking. Don't just blindly assume that functions will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

most likely, this is a permission problem where when the process is executed via the php-fpm, it can write to the location in question, but when run by your user account, the location is not writable.

to see the full details of what is happening with the script, try running it under strace

> strace php -q -f /home/user/public_html/file.php

Comment: well, the issue is that if i execute as it on shell, php -q /home/user/public_html/file.php i see that the file is created, but on put the command on a sh script it doesnt create :(

Comment: Can be an issue when the file name is specified without folder ?

Comment: there is no "put" command in bash/sh, unless you write the function yourself.  edit the question and give more details in order to get more help.  it is not clear what you are doing.

Comment: the issue was that i have declared only the file name without folder, strange, because in other servers it work without declare the path.